# Getting regional stats data from Steamworks API

Tags: steam-web-api, steamworks-api

I am working on a project that involves connecting to Steamworks Web API to fetch statistical information related to a number of games. I have a Web API Key and also, a list of Application IDs for the games I am interested in. After going through the entire Steamworks API I was unable to find an endpoint that satisfies my requirements.

I am looking for statistics related to different regions of the game. I want to know the number of active players in the region. The only relevant endpoint I found (not sure if this is what I am looking for is) `GetGlobalStatsForGame` endpoint found [here](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/webapi/ISteamUserStats). From what I understood, this endpoint can be used to get aggregated values for certain values related to the game. Now, in order for this to work, I need to know what available Global Stats are actually used by the game. Looking at the Global Stats documentation [here](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/features/achievements#global_stats) I can see that there is a function called `RequestGlobalStats`. However, this involves using a Steamworks sdk.

Is there a way I can request the global stats using the Steamworks Web API? If so, how can I do that? Are there any other endpoints that gives the name for each of these desired values?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way I can request the global stats using the Steamworks Web API?

You can check out what stats a game provideds with [GetSchemaForGame](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/webapi/ISteamUserStats) like this: `https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetSchemaForGame/v2/?key=YOUR_API_KEY&appid=730`.

CS GO for example does not have any regional game stats.

Unless developers supply that this information in their game statistics, there is no way with the API to find the information you are looking for.

You have to manually check every stats for the 400000+ games on Steam. I doubt many games have this information.

Comment: I already checkout the schema. Apparently it only lists a set of achievements for the game and a percentage of how many players have achieved that stat. I looking more into actual number of players in a region (like I can get a list of active game serves but I cannot query the server for active players with a Web API key; it needs a publisher key).